# How do I get the program to compile?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, calculator

I am trying to add an  ActionListener to one of the buttons in my Java program, but its method causes an error to occur. This is my code :

```
import javax.swing.*;//import the packages needed for gui
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class Calculator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame window = new JFrame("Window");// makes a JFrame
        window.setSize(300, 350);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());// makes the panel,
                                                    // textfield and buttons
        JTextField textField = new JTextField(20);
        JButton openbracket = new JButton("(");
        JButton closebracket = new JButton(")");
        JButton clearbutton = new JButton("C");
        JButton arcsin = new JButton("arcsin");
        JButton arccos = new JButton("arccos");
        JButton arctan = new JButton("arctan");
        JButton sin = new JButton("sin");
        JButton cos = new JButton("cos");
        JButton tan = new JButton("tan");
        JButton log = new JButton("log");
        JButton seven = new JButton("7");
        JButton eight = new JButton("8");
        JButton nine = new JButton("9");
        JButton four = new JButton("4");
        JButton five = new JButton("5");
        JButton six = new JButton("6");
        JButton one = new JButton("1");
        JButton two = new JButton("2");
        JButton three = new JButton("3");
        JButton zero = new JButton("0");
        JButton radixpoint = new JButton(".");
        JButton equal = new JButton("=");
        String values = null;
        class Listener implements ActionListener {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                values = values + "3";
                textField.setText(values);
            }
        }
        panel.add(textField);// adding all the things
        window.add(panel);
        panel.add(openbracket);
        panel.add(closebracket);
        panel.add(clearbutton);
        panel.add(arcsin);
        panel.add(arccos);
        panel.add(arctan);
        panel.add(sin);
        panel.add(cos);
        panel.add(tan);
        panel.add(log);
        panel.add(nine);
        panel.add(eight);
        panel.add(seven);
        panel.add(six);
        panel.add(five);
        panel.add(four);
        panel.add(three);
        panel.add(two);
        panel.add(one);
        panel.add(zero);
        panel.add(radixpoint);
        panel.add(equal);
        window.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The error messages I got were:

```
Calculator.java:36: local variable values is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final values = values + "3"; ^

Calculator.java:36: local variable values is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final values = values + "3"; ^

Calculator.java:37: local variable values is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final textField.setText(values); ^

Calculator.java:37: local variable textField is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final textField.setText(values); ^

4 errors
```

The compiler wants me to declare the String object and JTextField object as final, but if I declare them as final, I won't be able to change them. How do I make my calculator work without changing the objects?

Comment: The error is pretty clear.

Comment: make them `final` variables :)

Comment: You can easily make `textField` final. Not so easy with `values`, but the problem solves once you drop the idea to put everything in `main` (you can easily access class members from within inner classes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in order to make this code to compile you need to move `String` values and `JTextField textField` to be static members of main. This is because those from static main method.

```
public class Calculator {

static String values = null;
static JTextField textField = new JTextField(20);
...
```